# iPhone simulator doesn't update last frame and the UIView width doesn't fill the screen

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xlpagertabstrip

On my iPhone 7 plus it's working fine, but on the simulator iPhone 5 SE the `UIView` doesn't fill the screen **only after I switch tabs or I scroll the view**.

[image]

I'm using [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip) (9.0.0) to obtain two pages.

I added a `UIView` with the blue background for debugging purposes, but what I want tot achieve is a list with books.

I want the `UICollectionView` items to fill the entire screen, this is my implementation:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    print(String(format: "width is: %f", collectionView.bounds.width))

    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(90))
}
```

This is what I got in the console: `width is: 226.000000`, but after I scroll or I switch tabs, I get the following result: `width is: 320.000000`

I really don't know what's going on, the AutoLayout constraints are being set via storyboard from top-to-bottom and leading-to-trailing to fill the entire screen:

[image]

Please note: In the storyboard I've set the blue color to `UIView` because I wanted to know where the width error comes from. (I guess it's coming from elsewhere and not from the `UICollectionView`, because as you can see the `UIView` doesn't fill the entire screen horizontally).

I've added some debug logs to see the lifecycle of the `View Controllers`.

```
[ParentViewController]: viewControllers()
[ChildViewController]: viewDidLoad()
[ParentViewController]: viewDidLoad()
[ChildViewController]: viewWillAppear()
[ParentViewController]: viewWillAppear()
[ParentViewController]: viewDidLayoutSubviews()
[ChildViewController]: viewDidLayoutSubviews()
[ChildViewController]: viewDidLayoutSubviews()
[ChildViewController]: viewDidAppear()
[ParentViewController]: viewDidAppear()
```

(where: `ParentViewController` is the main `View Controller`, which holds the two child page `View Controllers`)

I don't know why the `[ParentViewController]: viewControllers()` is called before `viewDidLoad()`. Maybe the error comes from here?

This is my implementation:

```
class ParentViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        configureButtonBar()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    private func configureButtonBar() {
        // set the button bar style (color, font size, green bar size, paddings, etc)
    }

    override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {        
        let child1 = UIStoryboard.init(name: "ParentStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as! ChildViewController
        child1.pageTitle = "TAB 1"
        child1.entries = KData.shared().books

        let child2 = UIStoryboard.init(name: "ParentStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChildViewController") as! ChildViewController
        child2.pageTitle = "TAB 2"
        child2.entries = KData.shared().booksWithAuthors

        return [child1, child2]
    }
}
```

And the `ChildViewController` implementation:

```
class ChildViewController: UIViewController, IndicatorInfoProvider, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var pageTitle: String = ""
    var entries: [Book]? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        print(String(format: "width is: %f", collectionView.bounds.width))

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat(90))
    }
}
```

Comment: viewDidLoad in parent should always run before child. You can put log before `super.viewDidLoad()` to check again. Also can you check if collectionView frame is same as viewController frame?

Comment: @LinhQuangPham how do I check if it's the same frame?

Comment: @LinhQuangPham - I fixed it with removing `UICollectionView` and remade the whole screen with `UITableViewController`, made the cell and everything was working perfectly. I don't know what's going on, but I guess that somehow I didn't added the constraint for the `UICollectionView` or for the parent view or... really I don't why the `UICollectionView` didn't took the full width.

Comment: 2 way to check: print `self.view.frame` or use debug view hierarchy to see it.